How to deal with unreasonable strict parents?
I’m turning 16 in a little over a month. Since I started high school I actually started making friends but can’t make any plans with. I stay at home every miserable day, doing the same thing.
My dad dislikes:

how much I use my phone, but what else is there to do if I do chores & do my dual enrollment work?
my boy friend (I haven’t even told him I'm dating my boy friend, do I have pictures of him on phone and on the wall in my room)

mom also told him about my boy friend and said he was a good kid who had good grades & was very respectful & my dad said that he was going to be watching my behavior and how my grades were once I got back to school (I never slacked off so bad that I was failing. I got A’s B’s & C’s this sophomore year and my final grades were all mostly B’s)


finding out I'm doing something 'stupid' or that I'm hiding something from him
my friends, who he believes are useless self centered kids and get to do whatever they want

My dad's rules:

hand phone over at 9pm everyday, including weekends
curfew at 9pm
can't go out more than 2-3 hours
no door, instead have blackout curtain so any time I'm in my room I can be monitored and checked in on

I've tried talking to my mom for some type of understanding but it’s always back and forth. She understands me but doesn’t. I've been working and trying my best to fulfill whatever they put towards me. I started being a lot more responsible because I need to bring up the fact I have a boy friend to my dad & I don’t want an excuse for it to be a no like me getting bad grades or not doing enough around the house. I asked my mom a few days ago if I could go watch Inside Out 2 & she said she would take me this week since my dad will be out of town because while he’s in town we can’t do anything extra. She said she was going to take me so we could watch it but I didn’t want to watch it with her. The whole idea was for me to go with my bestfriend, her boy friend & my boy friend.
Everything I've had to do so far to even get to maintain my relationship with my boy friend is sneak around. During school I would leave school to spend more time with him or I just wouldn’t go into school at all just so we could actually do what we wanted to like get food or just be able to watch a movie at the comfort of his house. I can’t go out, we have a time limit, everything is rushed because “what if he calls”.  My mom told me my dad wouldn’t let me hang out with my boy friend like that even though he’s out of town. She said she’s trying to be chill about the fact I told her me & my boy friend got intimate like what did you expect? She got me pills herself to use as contraceptives because she assumes me and my boy friend are going to keep being intimate but she doesn’t expect me to wanna ask to see him. I got frustrated and started crying. She felt bad and said she understood me and she was going to let me know sometime this week to tell him to get ready so we could go to a park.
It’s been 18 days since I last saw him & I know it’s not a big deal but my boy friend and bestfriend are the only people I actually find comfort in. Me not being able to see him has been putting me in such a corner & I feel bad for even keeping him in the midst of this that I have going on. Now the excuse this week is that since my sister needs the car that means I'll have to stay inside yet again this whole week and not get to see my boy friend.
What I'd like to do:

meet my boy friend's family, as I've been invited. My boy friend has offered to let his mom talk to my parents
go out more, especially during summer

sleepover with friends, at least my best friend
go to the beach with boy friend and group of friends
go to movies and eat out after


be un-chaperoned by parents
not have plans cancelled last minute by parents
being happy for the flower I bring home from my boy friend
fewer unnecessary comments
maybe being emancipated, don't think the court will accept the proof I have/running away

neither my boyfriend or I are 16, so we can't get jobs



Please give me some advice if any. I sometimes can rely on my sister and spend the weekend at her house but as of right now I can’t as she’s wanting to move and is packing. I feel so drained out though & the worst part about it is that I've been getting lately more emotional so everything has been taking a toll on me because I'm sensitive. I have nowhere to look to or go. I don’t know what to do.

Can you please edit this. Break it up into paragraphs, and use capital letters in the usual way. Otherwise nobody is going to take the time to read it: walls of text like this are not easy to read, and you are asking kind people to spend their time helping. Then decide what question you want to ask us to help with and put it at the end. Make it more specific than "what do I do?". E.g. "How can I persuade my parents to ...?".

This has now been edited by @depperm, who has kindly done their best to structure what you wrote. Can you take a look at it and make some more edits if there is anything else? Or at least let us know that its what you wanted to say?

Also, take a look at some similar questions we have already answered. https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/42363/16-year-old-trying-to-deal-with-strict-invasive-parents-what-do-i-do?rq=1 https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/41340/what-do-i-do-as-a-highschooler-with-extremely-strict-parents?rq=1 https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/33077/what-can-i-as-a-teenager-do-about-my-insanely-strict-parents?rq=1

Is your phone locked when you hand it over, or are your parents able to look through it? (I don't think the latter is acceptable at your age BTW).

@PaulJohnson This is a sensitive issue, and the phone is a low priority item for the question. Legally, in most countries, any objects, items or property cannot be owned by a minor, but instead by their guardian or parent. It is within reason that a responsible parent may see it as prudent to be able to access phones of their dependents, especially in the interests of their welfare. The priority now is to reassure the OP that she is not in an unusual situation, she should stay calm and know that she would reach majority soon, and till then to do the best she can and work towards a good future.

@flox - can you give a reputable source for your claim that in most countries "items or property cannot be owned by a minor." I cannot find anything that supports your claim online.

Most kids have already developed some sort of privacy demands by around 9-11 (certainly by puberty). For example closing the door when going to the toilet is an early one. Closing the door when changing clothes / dressing is another. I find it troublesome that you are not allowed this similar privacy - especially when changing/dressing. Are your parents allowed the privacy of a closed door?

First of all, it is going to get better.
While 25 months can feel like a very long time, it is not that much compared to the rest of your life. Teenage runaways face incredible risks, and are very vulnerable to exploitation. I agree with your assessment that there is probably no legal shortcut either, so my primary advice is to hang in there until you are 18 and can tell your father to fuck off.
Try to understand his motivation
I don't mean this in a ``pretend like your father is a reasonable person'' way, but the better you understand what his motivation is, the better you can try and influence his behaviour. There might be a slim hope that he genuinely wishes well for you, and is simply clueless about decent parenting. For example, it is reasonable to be concerned over smartphone use and its impact on mental health amongst teenagers. Likewise, wanting you to excell at school fits in here. The other explanation coming to my mind is abusive controlfreak. I struggle to make sense of the fact that your room doesn't have a door any other way. Your mother being understanding but then catering to his whims fits in here as well.
If he is well-meaning and merely excessively strict,
you might be able to reach agreements spelling out expectations and liberties if the expectations are met. Stuff like ``As long as your grades remain above X, you get to meet your boyfriend once a week for Y hours.'' An abusive controlfreak is probably unwilling to enter such agreements, as they mean that control is taken away from him and vested in the agreement instead.
Can you recruit any adult to ``Team You''?
Your mother seems useless, and your sister may be busy enough with her own life. Is there any teacher at school, or maybe some other adult relative, which you can trust to be there for you? It is unlikely that they can do much for you concretely, but just having a source of advice and support can be very helpful.
Your boyfriend's mother
meeting with your parents could be very helpful. If your father is merely concerned, it might send the message that your boyfriend's home is not a lawless place, and that you'd be safe there. Otherwise, if he is somewhat self-aware, he might be unwilling to show his need for control to an outsider, and thus give in a little. However, he also might take her involvement as an attack on what is his, and take it out on you later - be cautious.
Prepare for the future.
In order to actually be able to tell your father to fuck off once you turn 18, you'll need to sort out a variety of things. Getting a college scholarship is ideal. Having some money would be very helpful, too. Be wary though, before you are 18 your dad can access your bank accounts, and depending on how they are set up, he might still be able to do in afterwards. Knowing where your documents are is helpful, etc.

Seek Understanding and Be Patient
I know this is difficult - but you are still a minor (in almost all countries) and still a dependency on your parents - in many ways you are quite young. What this means is your parents are still ultimately responsible for your well-being.
You should know parenting styles can vary and be very different between families, and some are more careful than others - try to see these situations from your parents (in particular your fathers) point of view to ascertain an understanding of their decisions and their concerns.
There are advantages to being 16 years old however. One such advantage is you are past the age of the early formative years, and you are now old enough to be in command of your emotions, to be diligent and to start thinking about your future career and life path.
From your question, there are many issues you raised - but the priorities at your stage in life is:

Work towards being competent: What this means is to study hard at school, diligently do school homework, learn new skills (like music, or extra curricular activities) to improve your capabilities such that when you do reach 18 (the age of majority) you have more options available to you.
Seek understanding: You may be dissatisfied with your parents, viewing them as strict, but rather than be confrontational have a calm discussion with them about what they are worried about. Don't get emotional, don't allow the conversation to be heated, just ask questions (and make no demands). This allows you to know the motivations behind your parents decisions.
Have healthy relationships within boundaries: I wouldn't seek at your age to have a relationship with someone outside of the bounds established by your parents - such a relationship that occurs in secrecy and causes conflict is not a fulfilling start. Ask instead of your parents their preferred boundaries for restricting contact knowing that boundaries are important in every healthy relationship, and seek then to know your partner within them. In your case, regular phone calls after school, accompanied contact after school, or weekend daytime contact within proximity to a responsible adult is reasonable and still allows plenty of exploration, of fun and of conversation with each other.

Overall, you must trust your parents to have your best interests at heart even if it is not visible to you at this moment, they are ultimately responsible for your wellbeing and your health and although you may view some aspects of your family as restrictive, keep in mind:

Until you are 18, they are legally responsible for your welfare
18 is only 2 years in the future, plenty of time in the meantime for you to sort out how, and in what form, you would like your future independence to look like.
The best way to be independent is to study hard in school, to ensure you have good employment, such that you have the ability to live and work when you wish. Without this you would always be dependent on others, including your family.
Be understanding of your parents until then, and keep in mind (especially if you desire your own children in the future) that responsibility may always look different depending on who is responsible for who.

In summary: be patient, be understanding and work towards a future you would like to see in the meantime.

"The best way to be independent is to study hard in school, to ensure you have good employment, such that you have the ability to live and work when you wish. " Agreed with the school part but I think employment should be the least of the worries of a 16 year old. In ideal circumstances, their worries should range from their health and safety, to having a good relationship with their family, to school, to their social life with friends.

@SyedM.Sannan - My point is that concentrating on school work and doing her best in that regard is the best way for her to live her life the way she wants. If she is doing terribly at school, then she would find it difficult to get a job and would always be dependent on her family. From the points she has raised, she would very much like to live differently to the way she is now, but this is not possible if she has no prospects and must always stay at home, or come back home, as a result. She wants to be independent but the only pathway to get there is through school and employment afterwards.

Well, from what I see in the question, she is doing decent at school. Those grades are average. I don't think adding the stress of studying to get a job besides every other mentioned problem of hers is gonna be healthy.

@SyedM.Sannan - Ok but if you did go back to your teens, and then didn't do well at school, then didn't earn your "many times more than the majority of programmers" then you would now still be living at home, under the purview of your parents (maybe with only a fast-food job, which barely keeps you alive). Your situation, however, is different to the OP's, she already stated her family situation is not satisfactory, whereas you may have been content with staying at home for many years. I think you should give yourself some credit to the good decisions you have already made in the past Syed.

I deleted my comments that included some personal info about me. I didn't realize it at the time of writing, but they contain a little info about me I'd rather not post publicly. I suppose I did add to the answer with my suggestion and gave you an alternative perspective as well, so it's not a total loss anyways.
